# What is the best method for storing multiple skills catagories in a database?

Tags: database, database-design, database-normalization

I have a table USER for which I would like to store skills against.

Obviously I intend to use a link table which allows the user to have multiple skills, however say for example the skills are split into categories such as 'technical skills' and 'managerial skills'.

Is it best to have a single SKILL table which stores the type of skill as well, and then a single link table USER_SKILL, or have separate tables MANAGERIAL_SKILL and TECHNICAL_SKILL and then also separate linking tables such as USER_MANAGERIAL_SKILL and USER_TECHNICAL_SKILL?

Comment: USER (1 - n) USER_SKILL (n - 1) SKILL. That's it. USER_SKILL could have a composite primary key of UserID and SkillID to avoid duplicates.

Comment: This doesn't answer how to define skill catagories

Comment: Rearranging for subtypes/supertypes is not DB normalization.

Comment: Thank you that suggested answer was useful I just have one more question. In the answer you suggested they refer to a policies and insurance inheritance. Say for example motor insurance can belong to another table too though such as USERS. So both a POLICY and a USER can have the same motor insurance. How does this work then as motor insurance inherits the PK from POLICY?

Comment: See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to learn to use @  to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter or 1 of certain other users about a comment. (Posters & followers aways get notified.) (Only followers got notified of your last comment.) Please ask a new (specific researched non-duplicate) question in (its own) question post, not in a comment.

Comment: @philipxy I don't think you've properly read my question as otherwise you would have understood what I meant. If you read the suggested answer on class inheritance, it says you can create sub-types of a class and 'inherit' the primary key from the main class to use as both a foreign and primary key.
This is the perfect example of specific, researched question, you just have not taken the time to understand what I am asking.

Comment: "inherits a PK" is not clear writing. I understand your post & the duplicate. You have no reason to think that I haven't read & understood them. This post is not researched, DB subtypes is an easily found faq & arises naturally from standard design methods. PS There is no "best" in engineering unless you define it in enough detail & give enough relevant details that all would agree on a valuation. And it is chaotically dependent on details. Even if that could be done it's too much for a question here. And then you would need to explain why you can't evaluate that yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is confusing, but i'll try to help with my understanding to it,

**First approach:**

Each user have multiple skills, and those skills are variant and they share the same **architecture** (idSkill, skillName, ......) and they have a **stagnant variation** is the skill type : Managerial or technical, in that case all you need is two tables :
`Skills` table and `Skills_Type` table.

**Second approach**

if we consider that each skill type has it own architecture such as

```
managerial_skills (idSkill, marketing, accounting, ...)
technical_skills (idSkill, web, databases, mobile, desktop ....)
```

then you need those tables also.

Comment: Thank you, also say for example you have a table JOB_TYPE(Id, name) and JOB(Id, job_type_id). If I want to use JOB_TYPE as a skill as well, should it be a separate table or could the same one be used? Or should there be a copy of the job types in the SKILL table?

Comment: you just need to add a foreign key to your skill table as (idSkill, idSkill_type , job_id_type ....)

Comment: No but the job type is being used AS a skill not with a skill

Comment: So would you just use job type Id for the skill type I'd?

Comment: For example another skill type would be job_skills, which just holds a job_type, but job_type is also used somewhere else so I cannot include the job_type directly in the job_skill.